# Not Exists giving zero rows

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, not-exists, notin

I have read many answers related to this and all are saying both works almost same except in the case of null values ,and not in works for a single column.

The task is to find each account number that has never been assigned to any line item in invoice_line_items table:

Correct query is:

```
SELECT 
    account_number, account_description
FROM
    general_ledger_accounts gl
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            account_number
        FROM
            invoice_line_items
        WHERE
            gl.account_number = account_number);
```

And if I remove gl.account_number = account_number it is returning zero rows.

I want to know :
1 ) Why there is a need for the statement gl.account_number = account_number in the subquery.
2 ) How the selection process is different in Not In and Not Exists.

Comment: I don't fully follow your question.  Your code is not different at all from `not exists`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wanna know why should I use the gl.account_number = account_number in the subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this using qualified column references throughout the query.  Also, the `select` in the subquery doesn't matter so I usually use `1`:

```
SELECT gl.account_number, gl.account_description
FROM general_ledger_accounts gl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM invoice_line_items ili
                  WHERE gl.account_number = ili.account_number
                 );
```

The subquery is a *correlated subquery* because the `where` clause connects the inner subquery on `ili` to the outer subquery on `gl`.  Conceptually, this is going through each account in `gl`.  The `where` clause evaluates to `true` when no rows match a particular `account_number`.

This is similar to `NOT IN`, except -- as you yourself point out -- when the `NOT IN` subquery returns `NULL` for *any* row.

Comment: what if i remove the where clause in the subquery

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi . . . This is will not be a correlated subquery.  The outer query will return either all rows (if there are any rows in `ili`) or no rows at all if there a no rows.